# MySQL, combining DISTINCT and JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, distinct

I have a table of users, called ..wait for it... "users".. and then another table which records users' activity called ...you'll never guess... "activity"..

I have an HTML table which shows the users in the `users` table, but I want to order the table by the users' last activity.

Here's my query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users` 
JOIN `activity` 
    ON `activity`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
    ORDER BY `activity`.`timestamp` 
        LIMIT 25
```

The problem here is that it shows multiple rows for each user since there are multiple records for each user in the `activity` table.

How can I alter the query to only show one record for each user and order them by the last activity in the activity table.?

I did experiment with using the "DISTINCT" keyword but no luck :/

Comment: you can select distinct username like 
DISTINCT(<username>)

Comment: My guess for activity table was "activities"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"one record for each user and order them by the last activity in the activity table.?"*

Couly try this? Assuming you need both user info and activity info.

```
SELECT users.*, a.*
FROM users INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
    FROM activity
    GROUP BY user_id
) x ON users.user_id = x.user_id 
INNER JOIN activity a ON x.user_id = a.user_id AND a.timestamp = x.max_timestamp
ORDER BY a.timestamp;
```

inner sub-query finds max_timestamp per user_id and outer JOIN finds activity has max_timestamp and user_id

Comment: a few minor errors but this is more or less what i'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Adelphia sorry for errors! and Thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not SQL solution, but what I would do is keep lastActivity column in Users table and update it when needed. Then sorting, filtering by this column would be very easy and efficient.

Comment: you're totally right, but at this point in the development stage that would be even more work.

Comment: Yeah, it totally depend where you use it and if it has to be efficient. If not SQL solution is simpliest.